# RMI. Ошибка при запуске клиента.

Tags: rmi, java

Использую NetBeance 7. Вот код:
Сервера

```
public class Server{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(System.getSecurityManager()==null) {  
            System.getProperties().put("java.security.policy", "policy.all");  
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());  
        }

        try
        {
            int port = 1099;
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);  
            reg.rebind("testrmi", new MessageImpl());

            System.out.println("Server is runing. Port " + port);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Клиента

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
                System.getProperties().put("java.security.policy", "policy.all");  
                System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());  
            }

            try {
                Registry  reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
                IMessage stub = (IMessage) reg.lookup("testrmi");

                System.out.print(stub.ReciveLast());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
    }
}
```

Сервер запускается нормально. Но постоянно при запуске клиента получаю ошибку:

```
Error: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
```

Жду ваших предложений.

Comment: Написано же что прав нет. ПОпробуйте от более привилегированного юзера запустить

Comment: и так администратор.. выше прав уже нет.

Comment: на винде от вашего единственного юзера запускаете?

Comment: да. и этот пользователь администратор.

Comment: если семерка стоит, то попробуйте собрать проект, а для запуска тыкнуть на бинарник правой кнопочкой и нажать "Запуск от Администратора"

Comment: не 7, а XP и я уже это пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

Сюда - [How to create an RMI system](http://patriot.net/~tvalesky/easyrmi.html) - смотрели?

> `problem: You get the following error when running the client
> java myRMIClient 127.0.0.1
> Exception occured: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)`